# Is it possible to run a query across from both projects azure DevOps? how can i do that?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, devops

So there two projects support and devops, I want to know if it is possible to run a query across both projects and how would i do that. the query should able to pull the epics and user stories from both projects? I am using azure devops tfs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may to check `Query across projects` and group clauses in a query ([Group clauses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/using-queries?view=azure-devops#group-clauses)).

[image]